# What do 'sub' and 'uid' mean in oauth response payloads?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

Background: There are plenty of oauth response payloads that include a `sub` or a `uid` field. Both seem to loosely be used to send a user id.

https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/signing-in-with-google/verifying-the-user-info/
https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oidc/#response-properties-3

What, if anything is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no practical difference, other than that the subject claim is in the official ietf spec, and the uid claim is not
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.2

I suspect that the uid claim is added to by some oauth providers to help identify a user more explicitly, because the subject claim in the spec is fairly general to support a broad set of scenarios. The entire oauth spec itself is quite general, so any differences between uid and the subject claim will probably be different for each oauth provider.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Anton's response: the user id should be immutable, so that if the user changes name their access to resources are not affected. Some vendors will set uid to a guid and sub to an email. So in some vendor scenarios can use the uid as a stable identifier for the user.